# How can I set a click listener for a RecyclerView list element in order to display an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog, onitemclicklistener, android-viewholder

I am trying to process the onItemClick event for a RecyclerView list element in order to display an AlertDialog when an item is selected. For that I placed click listener in the method bindViewHolder where I have access to the actual visual component but I still get the error

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Here is my ViewHolder class

```
public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView senderTextView;
    private TextView messageTextView;
    private TextView dateTextView;

    public MessageViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        senderTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatMessageSenderTW);
        messageTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatMessageTW);
        dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatMessageDateTW);
    }

    public void bindViewHolder(final ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        senderTextView.setText(chatMessage.getSender());
        messageTextView.setText(chatMessage.getMessage());
        dateTextView.setText(chatMessage.getDate());

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                myDialog
                        .setTitle("Confirmation")
                        .setMessage("Please confirm the item selection")
                        .setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I also checked the context that `v.getContext()` and is not null .

Comment: It looks like your view is not attached to window. But do smt in on bind is not good way. Try to delegate it via interface to your activity or fragment

Comment: Try to pass `Activity` context to holder and create `AlertDialog` with that context

Comment: I tried passing the context to the holder but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

wrap your XML layout inside a linearLayout and assign a click listener to the linear layout